# How to write junit test cases for if and else statements in Java?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, junit5, junit3

Here assuming this to be my simple method I want to write unit test cases covering if and else statement both ..

```
 public String getdata() {
        String existsQuery = "select ID from DEF where " +
        " NAME = ? "  ; 
        if (data) {
            if (existsQuery.indexOf("?") > 1) {
                existsQuery = existsQuery + " and ";
            } else {
                existsQuery = existsQuery + " where ";
            } 
            existsQuery = existsQuery + "ID = ?";
        }
        return existsQuery;
    }
```

I thought to call the call by creating object and assert but this is not the right way I think can someone help me with this ..Thanks in advance

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.planlytx.gson.pojo.FilterDef;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FilterdefUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testConcatenate() {
        Myunit myUnit = new Myunit();

        String result = myUnit.existSQL();

        assertEquals("select ...................", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to creat two or more objects of the class from getData() and than test it with assert otherwise you have no chance to check whether you methode is correct for each case you want to test.

Comment: any sample code @Marlon , you can help me with

Comment: Not enough info about the Myunit class. 
Can you creat an object of Myunit that fails the test?

Comment: Myunit class contains the above given method and data is a boolean value , which represent Id 2 @Marlon , if exists query doesnt have and or where then it fails

Comment: Try to generate an vaild and an invaild object ( even better when you generate more).
Than test all objects with assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
Also form my point of view you second if statement `if (existsQuery.indexOf("?") > 1) ` is always true.